# Difference of synchronized(Myfilter) and synchronized(this)

Tags: java

When I want to define synchronized block in a class which implements Filter interface is there any difference between synchronized (Myclass.class) and synchronized (this). A I know one object will create from Filters classes

Comment: `synchronized(Myclass)` doesn't compile.

Comment: One doesn't compile and the other does. If you mean synchronized(Myclass.class), then it synchonizes on the Myclass class whereas the other synchonizes on this instance of Myclass. Doesn't make a big difference in case of a filter, since it's nomally a singleton, but makes a huge difference if there are multiple instances of Myclass.